# Mysql: remote and local access

Tags: mysql, remote, mysql-connection

I have a gentoo where is installed a mysql server.
I need a remote access to this server, so I have modified the option *bind address* in the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf  bringing it from

*bindaddress: 127.0.0.1*

to

*bindaddress: MY_FOREIGN_IP*

And in this way I obtain a remote access to the mysql server.

The problem is that I have a local service that uses 127.0.0.1 ip to talk with my database. If I change the bindaddress option,  this service can't reach mysql server anymore.

There is a way to solve this issue, without using ssh tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to `0.0.0.0`, so that MySQL will accept connections to any IP address that exists on the host, including `127.0.0.1`.

Local clients can usually also connect via a unix socket; check the config for a `socket:` line. That may be a viable alternative to using `127.0.0.1`.

Make sure that the MySQL users have sufficient privileges from the client IP they are connecting from.